# How can I remove auto-created at boot ram-disk/virtual floppy and virtual machine from guest running in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, memory

I have a ramdisk in the form of a virtual floppy that boots immediately upon powering on the system.  It's running a virtual machine with a virtual bios and any DVDs or live disks or operating system I install go into this dynamic ramdisk and so I'm really a guest in my own computer.

I know there's a way to remove the ramdisk  but I'm unclear about it because how can I remove the very foundation that I'm operating from?  I followed these instructions to create and mount a ramdisk in linux using a live disk with no hdd attached, but I am not sure what to do next. link

https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux

I created a ramdisk using /dev/ram0 and then I looked inside and there were files so I deleted them, unmounted the ramdisk and deleted that as well.  Nothing happened as far as system crashes and when I rebooted the system was like new.

The live cd I'm working from is Parted Magic and there are 15 16mb ramdisks already showing when I check the directory.  I have also tried this with an install of mint 18 and ubuntu 16.10 but the result was the same, and since the ram disk is present and virtual machine operating without an installed OS, I decided that it didn't matter.

One other thing is that it doesn't matter if I install Windows (7,8,8.1,10) the ramdisk is present and actually what installs is a highly managed version of windows NT with the other OS merely used as a wrapper.

I hope this is clear.

1. Please, if you can, tell me whether I need to install an OS onto a hdd to deal with this.
2. Also, can you explain how I am to remove the very ramdisk that I'm operating from because I don't understand how that would work.

There's more, but I'll leave it at that and you can see I'm no expert but I appreciate the help.

Thanks